# Scala pipe patternmatching as a variable

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Often it is required to execute the same code for multiple values. With match this can be done using | (pipe) operator:

```scala
val state = "stopped"
val value = 0
(state, value) match {
    case ("running" | "pending", 0)   => println("running with no value")
    case ("stopped" | "cancelled", 0) => println("not running; no value")
    case ("running" | "pending", _)   => println("running with a value")
    case ("stopped" | "cancelled", _) => println("not running with a value")
    case _                            => println("unknown state")
}
```

Is there a method to write the pipes as a variable, eg:

```scala
val runningStates    = "running" | "pending"
val nonRunningStates = "stopped" | "cancelled"
```

So I can use these in the above pattern matching:

```scala
(state, value) match {
    case (runningStates, 0)    => println("running with no value")
    case (nonRunningStates, 0) => println("not running; no value")
    case (runningStates, _)    => println("running with a value")
    case (nonRunningStates, _) => println("not running with a value")
    case _                     => println("unknown state")
}
```

Comment: You may check for a custom extractor, another option would be to use a proper ADT with intermediate traits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your actual question is no, you can not write a pipe as a variable.

The Scala language reference in the Pattern Alternatives section ([8.1.12](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#patterns-alternatives)) says:

> A *pattern alternative p<sub>1</sub> | ... | p<sub>n</sub>* consists of
> a number of alternative patterns p<sub>i</sub>. All alternative patterns
> are type checked with the expected type of the pattern. They may not
> bind variables other than wildcards. The alternative pattern matches a
> value *v* if at least one its alternatives matches *v*.

so the pipe `|` is not implemented in the library but it is interpreted by the Scala compiler and it is context sensitive to pattern matching.